# Special permission to use LAPS cmdlet - not working if process is created from .NET application

Tags: c#, powershell

I can't find a way to execute any CmdLet's from the Module "LAPS" when trying to execute from .NET application (.NET framework 4.7 / 4.8)

All direct calls to Powershell using System.Automation are not working - even if I just open Powershell.exe via a Process I can't run any cmdlet from LAPS module - always telling me that the cmdlet can't be found

If I create a new tab for new Powershell instance - I can run it without any problems - what is the difference?!? Can start the program as Administrator - no difference! I there anything I can do to run CmdLet from LAPS from .NET application??? Seems to be any special permission that it is not working.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe");
        p.Start();
```

Then just type get-lapsadpassword - result in

The term 'get-lapsadpassword' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

Same is working in new Powershell instance when starting directly from Windows. WHY?

Comment: Are you using the same account to run the application that launches PowerShell? What happens if you run `Import-Module LAPS` before running `Get-LAPSADPassword`?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193798/laps-ps-module-not-available

Comment: Yes same account - can also start application "As Administrator" - Import-Module LAPS make no difference - and of course it is installed on the local machine (Win11)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is more than easy - LAPS-CmdLets are only available in 64bit mode - so if .NET application is build with X64 option the LAPS cmdlet
s are working!